# LINQ to SQL : Why don't these entities update?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Why don't the entities returned below update? They are null on the Get and remain null after the Save (in the db) even though the stocktakeid variable has values.

```
protected void GetPipelineState()
        {
            InventoryModelDataContext context = new InventoryModelDataContext(this.ConnectionString);
            var f = from pe in context.StockTakePipelines
                    where pe.StockTakeId == null
                    select pe;
            this.PipeLine = f;
        }

        protected void SavePipelineState()
        {
            InventoryModelDataContext context = new InventoryModelDataContext(this.ConnectionString);
            foreach (StockTakePipeline p in this.PipeLine)
            {
                p.StockTakeId = this.StockTakeId;
            }
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

**EDIT : Re PK**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing entities from the `context` local to `GetPipelineState()`, and then calling `SubmitChanges()` on the `context` local to `SavePipelineState()`.

Try something more like:

```
    protected IQueryable<StockTakePipeline> GetPipelineState(InventoryModelDataContext context)
    {
        return from pe in context.StockTakePipelines
                where pe.StockTakeId == null
                select pe;
    }

    protected void SavePipelineState()
    {
        using(InventoryModelDataContext context = new InventoryModelDataContext(this.ConnectionString));
        {
          foreach (StockTakePipeline p in GetPipelineState(context))
          {
              p.StockTakeId = this.StockTakeId;
          }
          context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Just a note for someone else finding this question. Another thing that will cause entities to not update is if they don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanging` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which they normally will, but won't if either you hand-code the class and forget to implement those, or if the table has no primary key (in which case there's no way to do an update on a given row anyway since it can't be identified, and the code gen drops the implementation of those now-pointless interfaces as an optimisation).

Comment: Isn't that querying the db for all qualifying records once for every record?

Comment: @rism No, it's exactly the same as your code, except it uses a passed-in context to generate the `IQueryable<StockTakePipeLine>`. Upon `foreach` that query is executed once, and the results are iterated through (single call to `GetPipelineState()`, single hidden call to `GetEnumerator()`, multiple hidden calls on `MoveNext()` until it returns false, matching hidden calls on `Current` to obtain the current value for `p`).

Comment: What type did you have for the `PipeLine` field or property? If it was `IEnumerable<StockTakePipeline>` or `IQueryable<StockTakePipeline>` then the above will have the same performance. If it was anything else then the above is likely to be a bit faster (except the fact that `SubmitChanges` has something to do will obviously make it slower overall!).

Comment: It was IQueryable<StockTakePipeline>. Thx

Comment: Then it's exactly the same as your code, bar the passed-in context.

Comment: @rism What about the "edit for other people finding this". Relevant to you?

Comment: No unfortunately. Iv edited my post and included the schema re:PK and the class have the appropriate events etc. (They weren't hand coded).

Comment: Well, assuming you didn't turn off object tracking, no flaw stands out to me. If it were my code I'd be down to checking the SQL in SQLProfiler, and stepping through the code (including a breakpoint on the getter and setter for `StockTakePipeline.StockTakeId`).

Comment: Ok my "copy" of your code wasn't quite right. In GetPipelineState i left in my original var f and returned f. When I made GetPipelineState just "return" it worked. But I now don't know why? Whats the difference between putting the query in a var and not before returning it? Thx

Comment: Beats me. If that was the only difference I would totally expect it to work - especially if it works now, so it wasn't that there was a mistake in my code. Especially so if it was `var` as then there's no hidden casts etc.